# Text Extraction, Not Image Extraction

Tags: pdf, itext

Please help me understand if my solution is correct.

I'm trying to extract text from a PDF file with a LocationTextExtractionStrategy parser.  I'm getting exceptions because the ParseContentMethod tries to parse inline images?  The code is simple and looks similar to this:

```cs
RenderFilter[] filter = { new RegionTextRenderFilter(cropBox) };
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter);
PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, pageNumber, strategy);
```

I realize the images are in the content stream but I have a PDF file failing to extract text because of inline images. It returns an UnsupportedPdfException of "The filter /DCTDECODE is not supported" and then it finally fails with and InlineImageParseException of "Could not find image data or EI", when all I really care about is the text.  The BI/EI exists in my file so I assume this failure is because of the /DCTDECODE exception. But again, I don't care about images, I'm looking for text.

My current solution for this is to add a filterHandler in the InlineImageUtils class that assigns the `Filter_DoNothing()` filter to the DCTDECODE filterHandler dictionary.  This way I don't get exceptions when I have InlineImages with DCTDECODE.  Like this:

```
private static bool InlineImageStreamBytesAreComplete(byte[] samples, PdfDictionary imageDictionary) {
    try {
        IDictionary<PdfName, FilterHandlers.IFilterHandler> handlers = new Dictionary<PdfName, FilterHandlers.IFilterHandler>(FilterHandlers.GetDefaultFilterHandlers());
        handlers[PdfName.DCTDECODE] = new Filter_DoNothing();
        PdfReader.DecodeBytes(samples, imageDictionary, handlers);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

public class Filter_DoNothing : FilterHandlers.IFilterHandler
{
    public byte[] Decode(byte[] b, PdfName filterName, PdfObject decodeParams, PdfDictionary streamDictionary)
    {
        return b;
    }
}
```

My problem with this "fix" is that I had to change the iTextSharp library.  I'd rather not do that so I can try to stay compatible with future versions.

Here's the PDF in question:
https://app.box.com/s/7eaewzu4mnby9ogpl2frzjswgqxn9rz5

Comment: Inline images are a pain because the end sequence marking the end of an inline image stream can also occur inside the image stream (as part of the data). We've fixed problems like this in recent versions of iTextSharp. Which version are you using? If you're using the latest version, we might be facing a regression.

Comment: I'm using iTextSharp 5.5.6.

Comment: OK, I've created a ticket in our internal issue tracker so that our engineers can take a look.